# Round negative float up or down depending on the value behind the comma

Tags: c#, math, floating-point

So as I'm trying to round a float value up or down. Now I currently use this code:

```
var calc_points = (distance_in_km - total_dist) * 20;
Debug.WriteLine("Negatief! " + calc_points);
points = (int)Math.Abs(calc_points);
```

Where `distance_in_km` is a `float`, `total_dist` is a `float`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Examples of in and output;

```
 0.33425 =>  0
-0.33425 =>  0
 1.44445 =>  2
-1.44445 => -2
 3.2954  =>  3
-3.2954  => -3
```

It's basic maths but I have no clue on how I should do this in code, since `Math.Round()` does not the "normal" math....

Comment: Rounding doesn't normally introduce a factor of 10... but if a factor of 10 is what you want, try simply `Math.Round(input) / 10`.

Comment: If you want a *specific* rounding, could you, please provide more *examples*? Especially differences from standard `Math.Round` behaviour and *border cases* (e.g. what is the expected result for `-1.5`? `-2.5`?)

Comment: The thing is, if you have for example `1.44446`, it should be rounded to `2`, because the `6` is larger then 5, so it gets `1.4445`, then rounds again to `1.445`, because round up if 5 or bigger, and so on, untill no more digits behind the `.` are left

Comment: That's not how any definition of rounding works. If you need a non-normal rounding, you need to provide the specific rules for all inputs. Also, in your sample code, where do you expect the "rounding" to occur?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong here?_ Your requirements/definition for 'rounding' isn't what normal rounding represents. Should first properly define those.

Comment: I have added samples.

Comment: Your examples aren't consistent. You say `0.33425 => 0`, but `1.44445 => 2`. Fractional part in both is less than half, so normally they should round down. On what do you base this rounding criteria? In other words, if `0.33425` rounds down, so should `1.44445`.

Comment: Last number of `1.44445` is `5`, so the `5` adds `1` to the first `4` behind before the `5`, which gives us `1.4445`, then last `5` is again to round up and we move on, add 1.. untill you get `2` as result.

Comment: OK so now your criteria is clear; you're looking for a _gradual_ rounding where you round up/down each digit and then move to the next till you reach an integer. That wasn't clear at all at the beginning. In that case, you can't simply use `Math.Round()` and be done with it, you'll have to round repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *round* the `value` then put [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_):

```
  float value = -1.999969f; 

  // Scale: value / 10 then round up to 1 digit after the decimal point (-0.2)
  double result = Math.Round(value / 10.0, 1);
```

If you want to *represent* `value` only (we want to keep `value` as it is, but print it out with just one digit after the decimal point), use *formatting* (`F1` format string - `1` digit after the decimal point)

```
  float value = -1.999969f 

  // Scale and then represent with 1 digit after the decimal point (-0.2)
  Debug.WriteLine($"Negatief! {value / 10.0:F1}");
```

**Edit:** If you want a *special kind rounding* (see comments to the question):

> If you have for example `1.44446`, it should be rounded to 2, because
>   the `6` is larger then `5`, so it gets `1.4445`, then rounds again to `1.445`,
>   because round up if `5` or bigger, and so on, untill no more digits
>   behind the `.`

we have to invent the formula. As we can see

```
 0.444444....444 -> 0
 0.444444....445 -> 1
```

which means that we can adapt `Math.Round` for these rules: in order to push `0.(4)` to `0.5` we can multiply fractional part by `1.25`:

```
 0.44444...444 * 1.25 = 0.5
```

Sample code:

```
  private static int MyRound(double value) {
    return (int)value + (int)Math.Round((value - (int) value) * 1.125);
  }
```

Or, if we want `double` as a result

```
  private static double MyRound(double value) {
    return Math.Truncate(value) + Math.Round(value % 1 * 1.125);
  }
```

Tests:

```
  double[] tests = new double[] {
     1.44446,
     1.4444,
    -1.44444,
    -1.4445,
     0.33425,
    -0.33425,
     3.2954,
    -3.2954,
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(item => $"{item,10} => {MyRound(item),2}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
   1.44446 =>  2
    1.4444 =>  1
  -1.44444 => -1
   -1.4445 => -2
   0.33425 =>  0
  -0.33425 =>  0
    3.2954 =>  3
   -3.2954 => -3
```

Comment: I think my solution is this; `System.Math.Round (n, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 3.15`

Comment: @Robin: Well, `Math.Round(-1.444469, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);` returns `-1.44` when you put "it needs to be `-0.1`"

Comment: @Robin: `MidpointRounding` acts if we are *exactly* in the *middle*, e.g. `Math.Round(-2.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) == -3` when `Math.Round(-2.5, 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven) == -2`; I sorry, but I can't derive the right `MidpointRounding` from the examples in the question

Comment: I don't know what you think *round up* means, but you're using it wrong.

Comment: `(int)value + (int)Math.Round((value - (int) value) * 1.125);` did the trick here! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want is some type of "gradual" rounding, where you round one fewer place each time until you get to 0 decimal places. To do that, you will have to actually round down one place at a time.

Implemented in an extension method:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public static double GradualRoundingTo0(this double d) {
    var dp = ((SqlDecimal)(Decimal)d).Scale;
    return Enumerable.Range(1, dp).Aggregate(d, (a, n) => Math.Round(a, dp - n, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
}
```

You will need the `using` to implement the trick I used to count the number of fractional places for rounding.